# How to get a single file from a bare Git repository?

Tags: git

I have a remote repository where I have created a git bare repo. 
But I would like when I will push changes to this repo, automatically, git places a .jar from the \target folder (working repo) in a specific folder on remote server.

I did post-execute hook like this:

```
$ cat > hooks/post-receive
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/ubuntu/www/mydomain.com
export GIT_WORK_TREE
git checkout -f
```

With this I have my working copies in that folder, but now I want to change this and only to have a specific file: myfile.jar

How can I modify this script for achieve this?

Comment: Well, you're halfway there. Now it depends on where you want your jar created!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [`git show`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html) which is able to get the object's contents given a commit-ish and a pathname to that object as recorded in the commit referenced by that commit-ish.  It writes the object's contents to the standard output so you have to redirect it to a target file (which will be created and/or overwritten).

```
$ cat > hooks/post-receive
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/ubuntu/www/mydomain.com
export GIT_WORK_TREE
git show HEAD:path/to/that.jar >"$TARGETDIR"/that.jar
```